# M1: Google Indexing different currency (USD) as oppose to default currency (GBP)

Tags: magento-1.9, multicurrency, google-product-feeds

We have a single store website with 3 currencies (GBP, USD, EUR) where the **default currency** is **GBP**. The other currencies are selectable using the currency selector. Currently Google is indexing & caching everything with USD prices.

What would be the cause of this and is there a solution?

N.B. new sessions should use GBP & There is **NO Geo IP** functionality.

Comment: maybe some sourcecode is useful here... can you post the sourcecode of the richsnippets?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your feed, may be price in product feed are in USD which you have uploaded to the Google.

Try to upload the new feed with price in GBP.